# How to make bash remember history of previous sessions?

Tags: bash, terminal, history

I have MacOSX but this should be *NIX-generic.
In my computer at work, my bash shell remembers history from previous sessions, even if I just opened a new terminal.
In my computer at home, this doesn't happen.
I have the same OS in both machines and I don't have any history related setting in .bash_profile.
How could I set this up on my home computer so it remembers history across sessions?

Comment: also asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/50649/7057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that you are running bash at home.  This can be done with the following

```
echo $SHELL
```

or

```
echo $0
```

or

```
ps -p $$
```

Output on method one should be something like

```
/bin/bash
```

Method 2 should output should be

```
-bash
```

Method 3 should output some process with BASH in it.

If you are truly running bash there should be a .bash_history file under your home folder.  Your user account might not be setup properly if you are not receiving a history.

Some environmental options to consider

HISTIGNORE
HISTSIZE
HISTFILE

To check these settings use:

```
echo $HISTSIZE
echo $HISTIGNORE
```

To update use:

```
export HISTSIZE=9000
```

If you are not using BASH as your shell you can mod your account (if you have privs) by:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash <username>
```